# How to interpolate the escape characters stored in a variable in perl?

Tags: perl

I have written a perl code to get the source filename ,destination filename, pattern and replacement string.The below one is the code I have written.

```
chomp($input=<stdin>);   #source file name.
open SRC, $input;        #opening the file .

chomp($input=<stdin>);   #destination file name.
open DES, ">>$input";     #opening the file.

chomp($pattern=<stdin>);   #pattern to be matched.

chomp($replace=<stdin>);   #replacement string.

while(<SRC>){
    s/$pattern/$replace/g;
    print DES $_;
}
```

I have written this code to replace the particular value in a file and store it in another file. As per the code if I have given the pattern " "(white space) and replacement string as \n ,it should give the output as follows.

#### Sample Input

```
Hai hello this for testing .
```

#### sample output

```
Hai 
hello
this
for
testing
.
```

But it has given the output as follows.

#### Output

```
hai\nhello\nthis\nis\nfor\ntesting\n.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Tip: Use `s/$pattern/interpolate($replace)/egr` (not `$replace = interpolate($replace); s/$pattern/$replace/gr`) to handle `$1` when using String::Interpolate

Answer (score 7):

Please, you *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every Perl program you write, end declare every variable with `my`. You should also use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`, and *always* check that a call to `open` has succeeded. So

```
open DES, ">>$input"
```

should be more like

```
open my $des_fh, '>>', $input or die qq{Unable to open "$input" for appending: $!}
```

---

You could use `eval` for this, but it's much cleaner and safer to use the [`String::Interpolate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/String::Interpolate) module, which provides access to the code within perl that processes double-quoted strings. It exports The `interpolate` function, which will correctly translate all variable references as well as any special characters like `\n` or `\t`

It would look like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use String::Interpolate 'interpolate';

chomp( my $in_file = <> );
open my $in_fh, '<', $in_file or die qq{Unable to open "$in_file" for input: $!};

chomp( my $out_file = <> );
open my $out_fh, '>>', $out_file or die qq{Unable to open "$out_file" for input: $!};

chomp( my $pattern = <> );

chomp( my $replace = <> );
$replace = interpolate($replace);

while ( <$in_fh> ) {
    s/$pattern/$replace/g;
    print $out_fh $_;
}
```

Note that you could enter the parameters on the command line instead of having your program prompt for them

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use String::Interpolate 'interpolate';

my $pattern = shift;
my $replace = shift;
$replace = interpolate($replace);

print s/$pattern/$replace/gr while <>;
```

You would call this like so

```
$ perl replace.pl ' '  '\n'  sample.txt
```

and you can redirect the output to a file in the normal way

```
$ perl replace.pl ' '  '\n'  sample.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend the functions provided by [String::Substitution](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String::Substitution).

Replace

```
s/$pattern/$replace/g;
```

with

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_modify );

gsub_modify($_, $pattern, $replace);
```

This won't just handle `\n`; it'll handle `$1` too!

---

Notes:

- There is a lot of advice to use `eval EXPR` (sometimes disguised as `/ee`), but this is very error-prone and dangerous.
- In the past, I've provided solutions that use String::Interpolate, but the module provides an extremely weird interface.